# Как убрать пустоту над текстом в блоке CSS

Tags: html, css, изображения

Подскажите, как убрать пустоту над и под текстом в этих блоках.

```
            <div class="digits_heading_title">
              <p class="digits_heading_title_content">Цифры и факты</p>
            </div>

            <div class="digits_heading_subtitle">
              <p class="digits_heading_subtitle_content">про кошек и их хозяев</p>
            </div>
```

Вот как выглядит визуально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, чтобы все границы блока совпадали с границами контента.

Update: Код из CSS:

```
.digits_heading {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Внутренние блоки никак не стилизованы.

Comment: обнулите margin & padding - `margin: 0; padding: 0;`

Comment: Приложите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), вместо несвязанных отрывков кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет кода стилей. Из предположений - вы сделали их блоками с отступами или поставьте высоту линии на 0:

```
CSS
line-height: 0;
```